# How to pass argument to wp_footer hook with data from a template

Tags: hooks

I need to display a script just after all my js files loaded via `wp_enqueue_script`

In my functions.php :

```
function list_hotels($hotels){ ?>
    <script>
        var positions = [];
        positions = <?php echo json_encode($hotels); ?>
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'list_hotels', 50, 1);
```

In my template (there is an available `$hotels` var which is an array) :

```
do_action( 'wp_footer', $hotels );
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Try changing `function list_hotels($hotels){ ?>` to `function list_hotels(){ global $hotels; ?>` and you *may* also need to declare the `$hotels` as a global variable. E.g. `global $hotels; $hotels = array( ... );`.

Comment: @SallyCJ I hope you are joking when suggesting that anyone should use globals ;)

Comment: Hehe.. but I'd actually provide a more appropriate answer if @WilliamOde replied... =)

Answer (score 2):

The best way of passing PHP variables to JavaScript is using [wp_localize_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/), which helps to localizes a registered script with data for a JavaScript variable.

Here is a solution in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282503/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-to-an-action-hook-function), from where you can get idea to fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to pass extra parameters to hooks, in addition to the ones they declare is by using [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

in your case it will be something like

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () use ($hotels) { list_hotels($hotels) });
```

The `use` keyword enable sharing of variables between the context in which the closure is declared and the one it is being used (meaning, when the action is actually executed).